# Remote reloading a view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitabview

I was wondering if there is a way to reload a view controller inside one tab from another tab. This is my scenario

1. Tab controller has 2 or more tabs
2. Tab 1 has a view controller which has views created based on some conditions
3. Tab 2 is  a settings page, where some app settings can be changed
4. How can i reload content inside tab 1 when settings in tab 2 are changed?

IS there something like tab bar -> tab -> view controller -> reload viewDidLoad?

Thanks

Comment: @vikingosegundo No need for 'iphone' in the title. That's what the tags are for. I also see no need to delete the "ios" tag, and the "objective-c" tag is misleading since this question is about Apple's implementation of Objective-C, which is Cocoa. It has nothing to do with Objective-C specifically, much in the same way that it has nothing to do with Xcode, which is why I deleted that out of the title, too.

Comment: Hm, i guess our two edits were overlaping. I didnt add iPhone, i just didnt delete it.

Comment: and I exchanged xcode with cocoa-touch. i didnt add any else

Comment: ok, i added objective-c.

Comment: Thanks guys, will remember this in future and add the appropriate tages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way I solve this problem is by having a "Settings"-type object (Model) that is observed by my view controllers. In your case, you'd initialize it in your app delegate, pass it along to the view controllers for Tab 1 and Tab 2, which would then use KVO to observe it. You'd also directly modify it in Tab 2's view controller.

You could also use a `NSNotifcation` to signal a change in the settings to any view controller that wants to observe it.

Comment: Hi shaggy, i think i understand what you meant, just that i am not very sure of how to implement it.. can you point me to some examples?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/962591/161161 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3720232/161161 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2224285/161161

Comment: I did find the solution in the threads you have mentioned, thanks shaggy - voting for you :)